# Other polynomial representation

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions

In my derivation (because of derivatives), I have (or I think that it is better) to write the polynomial (1) in the form (2):
$$\tag{1}
p(n)=p_0+p_1 n+\cdots+p_r n^r
$$

$$\tag{2}
p(n)=p'_0P(n,0)+p'_1 P(n,1) +\cdots+p'_r P(n,r)
$$
where $P(n,k)=n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$. E.g. $P(n,0)=$, $P(n,1)=n$, $P(n,2)=n(n-1)$.

> (A) Is there a name for the representation (2)?
>   (B) Is there a method to go from $(p_i)$ to $(p'_i)$ and vice versa? (with method I mean a closed formula like the Newton binomial formula)

At the end I have the advantage that 
$$
x^k\frac{d}{d^kx}x^n=P(n,k)x^n.
$$

I added the tag *generating-functions* because this is the topic I'm looking at now; and people familiar with it have done ton of times this computations.

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you. It seams to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a well known alternative basis for polynomials
$$
P(n,k) = n\left( {n - 1} \right) \cdots \left( {n - k + 1} \right) = \prod\limits_{j = 0}^{k - 1} {\left( {n - j} \right)}  = n^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } 
$$
which is called [Falling Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

The conversion is given by the [Stirling Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number)
of 1st kind (unsigned) in square brackets and of 2nd kind in curly brackets.
$$
\eqalign{
  & x^{\,j}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,j} {\left\{ \matrix{
  j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right\}\,x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \; = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,j} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j - k} \left\{ \matrix{
  j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right\}\,x^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \;\quad {\rm integer }j \ge 0  \cr 
  & x^{\,\underline {\,j\,} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,j} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j - k} \left[ \matrix{
  j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right]x^{\,k} }  = \;\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,j} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,i\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j - i} \,\left[ \matrix{
  j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right]\left\{ \matrix{
  k \cr 
  i \cr}  \right\}\,x^{\,\overline {\,i\,} } } } \quad {\rm integer }j \ge 0  \cr 
  & x^{\,\overline {\,j\,} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,j} {\left[ \matrix{
  j \cr 
  k \cr}  \right]x^{\,k} } \; = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,j} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,i\, \le \,k} {\left[ \matrix{
  j \hfill \cr 
  k \hfill \cr}  \right]\left\{ \matrix{
  k \cr 
  i \cr}  \right\}\,x^{\,\underline {\,i\,} } } } \;\quad {\rm integer j} \ge 0 \cr} 
$$